# Move zip files from one server to hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume

What is the best approach to move files from one Linux box to HDFS should I use `flume` or `ssh` ?

SSH Command:

```
cat kali.txt | ssh user@hadoopdatanode.com "hdfs dfs -put - /data/kali.txt"
```

Only problem with SSH is I need to mention password every time need to check how to pass password without authentication.

Can `flume` move files straight to HDFS from one server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can make passwordless-ssh, then transfer files without entering password

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you create a script in python for example which does the job for you

Answer (score 0):

You could install hadoop client on a Linux box that has the files. Then you could "hdfs dfs -put" your data directly from that box to hadoop cluster.